# Reverse polarity of cells connected in series and net EMF

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, batteries

When 2 cells are connected in series with reverse polarity, the net emf of the combination is difference of individual emfs, but clearly this is not the case practically, since cells connected in reverse polarity do not work. What is the matter here?

Comment: The “reversed” cell would be acting as an electrolytic cell, rather than as a galvanic cell. What could go wrong? ;-)

Comment: I thought they were dry cells

Comment: What is the difference between an electrolytic cell and a dry cell here?

Comment: A simple dry cell “battery” derives its energy from the oxidation and reduction reactions of its chemical constituents. Forcing substantial current through in the reverse, i.e., electrolytic, direction is not a good idea for a non-rechargeable cell. You are basically trying to reverse reactions that, by cell design, should not be reversed.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more thing, so what principle enables an electrolytic cell to work even with reverse polarity?

Comment: Please look at my answer over in the chemistry SE: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/153076/79678. The figures I drew there should help.